# Unable to use GitLab integration behind proxy

Tags: proxy, gitlab, webhooks, mattermost

Is there a way to configure `mattermost notifications` from GitLab which is behind a http-proxy to another Mattermost server (not behind this proxy)?

I've tried from the web UI but I have the error *Something were wrong on our end*. I've tried to curl the Mattermost with this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Hello, this is some text\nThis is more text. :tada:"}' https://mattermost_webhook_url
```

It doesn't work, but if I do `export https_proxy=the_https_proxy`, then the curl works and I have the notification in Mattermost. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding env variable `https_proxy` for this?
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/43341

It solved my issue